# Excel: Bad formatted date

Tags: excel

I've got a field in a downloaded CSV like this:
October 15th 2017, 12:00:00.000

I want to split this field into a real date field and a time field. Can't find any good solution on how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put this `UDF()` in a standard module:

```
Public Function INeedADate(s As String) As Date
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    brr = Split(arr(0), " ")
    INeedADate = DateValue(Mid(brr(1), 1, Len(brr(1)) - 2) & " " & brr(0) & " " & brr(2))
End Function
```

Then with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INeedADate(A1)
```

In **C1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))
```

[image]

NOTE:

There is nothing special about the `UDF()`.  It can easily be replaced by an equivalent formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016, import the CSV file using new wizard

- Split the field on the comma
- The Time field should automatically convert
- In the date field, replace `rd`, `th`, `st` with `comma` (three steps)
- Change the "type" to `Date`

If you have an older version, after splitting on the comma, do three nested `SUBSTITUTES` to remove the ordinal tokens

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"nd",","),"rd",","),"th",",")
```

Preceding that formula with either the `DATEVALUE` function, `VALUE` function, or a double unary will then convert it to a "real date"